# choice between xmpp or java servlet for a chat server

Tags: java, servlets, xmpp, forum, irc

I have done a some (but not advanced level expert) research for xmpp protocol and learned java and Java EE for making JSPs and Servlets.

I want to make a web based chat system. obviously that requires javascript, css, html based front end UI (and if done with xmpp, some desktop xmpp clients can be used).

I really cant make a decision what to use. xmpp or java servlets (as they can be used besides typical jsp websites). It can be done in both. there are open-source xmmp servers which I can use and customize or I can write my own servlet based server application from scratch.

should I make it xmpp compliant or just use a Socket class in java and dont care about xmpp?

I depict the chat server having similar attributes like a blend of IRC, facebook chat, and a forum like stackoverflow

This is a question of longterm strategy, planning ahead for benefits, features and problems or limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) is a protocol. Java EE is a technology.

XMPP has implementations [in Java, but also for lots of other technologies](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/)

Your question makes no sense: choice between a leather seat and a family car...

Well, you can pick both the family car and the leather seat. Or the sports car with a leather seat. Or a SUV with a leather seat. ...

---

Edit according to your comment:

> I wanted to ask that should I make it xmpp compliant or just use a
>   Socket class in java and do all workings with port 80

Why not use an existing Java library implementing the XMPP protocol? You should be saving time by not re-inventing the wheel ...

> "should I make it xmpp compliant or just use a Socket class in java and dont care about xmpp?"

You should use existing libraries and protocols if they fit your needs. If an existing server can do what you want then go for it. If it does not but you can customize it fairly easily, then go for it, if not, then create your server using existing XMPP libraries if XMPP covers your needs.

You are the only one who knows what you need. You have the XMPP protocol specifications to decide if it covers them or not.

Comment: I know, I couldnt make it clear though. I wanted to ask that should I make it xmpp compliant or just use a Socket class in java and do all workings with port 80

Comment: you mean theres an xmpp class/ library made for xmpp applications in java? well, even though. If I use it. I would have to code the server from scratch. I heard openfire is a java based xmpp compliant chat server.

Comment: what difference will it make? the question was, why choose an option?

Comment: Again edited (my last edit) for that question.

Comment: Thanks! nice answer. further more, I installed openfire chat server which is a java based xmpp compliant server. Now, does it makes a difference If I had used Tomcat and only servlet based application only (which might get integrated with the jsp pages of the web based client UI )  rather having a seperate openfire server and a seperate UI?

Answer (score 0):

use java with JSP and Servlets and Javascript with Ajax using probably Apache Wicket. Keep most of the java source in the Servlets.

Comment: do you mean to use simple sockets classes in java servlets? why not use xmpp?

Comment: well I don't know what xmpp is.. but ya I see no reason sockets wouldn't work fine. unless you are talking about http tunneling to work around firewalls.